# Display the calculations for the year if show = True

Tags: python, function

I am wondering if I did correctly. The "Print to screen if show = True", is confusing me a bit on how to implement into my code so the rest of my functions will work properly.

```
# Display results of scenario

def display_flow(show,                   # print to screen if show = True`
             scen_year,
             age,
             s_bal,
             bal_pv,
             inv_gains,
             ann_savings,
             ss_payment,
             major_inc,
             major_exp,
             tax_rate,
             tar_ret_spend,
             net_ret_spend,
             ret_pre_tax_spend,
             taxes,
             end_bal
             ):
""" display_flow() test output
    >>> display_flow(show              = True,
    ...             scen_year         = 0,
    ...             age               = 60,
    ...             s_bal             = 100000,
    ...             bal_pv            = 100000,
    ...             inv_gains         = 1000,
    ...             ann_savings       = 1000,
    ...             ss_payment        = 1000,
    ...             major_inc         = 1000,
    ...             major_exp         = 1000,
    ...             tax_rate          = 0.15,
    ...             tar_ret_spend     = 50000,
    ...             net_ret_spend     = 40000,
    ...             ret_pre_tax_spend = 60000,
    ...             taxes             = 10000,
    ...             end_bal           = 120000
    ...             )
    Year             : 0
    Age              : 60
    Start Bal        : 100,000.00
    Start Bal PV     : 100,000.00
    Invest Gains     : 1,000.00
    Ann Savings      : 1,000.00
    SS Payment       : 1,000.00
    Major Inc        : 1,000.00
    Major Exp        : 1,000.00
    Tax Rate         : 15.00%
    Targ Ret Spend   : 50,000.00
    Net Ret Spend    : 40,000.00
    Ret Pre-tax Spend: 60,000.00
    Taxes            : 10,000.00
    End Bal          : 120,000.00

"""
#==============================================================================================     


 print(' Year               :'  , scen_year, 
          '\n Age               :',age,
          '\n Start Bal         :', (format(s_bal, ',.2f')),
          '\n Start Bal PV      :', (format(bal_pv, ',.2f')), 
          '\n Invest Gains      :', (format(inv_gains, ',.2f')),
          '\n Ann Savings       :', (format(ann_savings,',.2f')),
          '\n SS Payment        :', (format(ss_payment, ',.2f')),
          '\n Major Inc         :', (format(major_inc, ',.2f')),
          '\n Major Exp         :', (format(major_exp, ',.2f')),
          '\n Tax Rate          :', (format(tax_rate, '.2%')), 
          '\n Targ Ret Spend    :', (format(tar_ret_spend, ',.2f')),
          '\n Net Ret Spend     :', (format(net_ret_spend, ',.2f')),
          '\n Ret Pre-tax Spend :', (format(ret_pre_tax_spend, ',.2f')), 
          '\n Taxes             :', (format(taxes, ',.2f')), 
          '\n End Bal           :', (format(end_bal, ',.2f')))
    
    
#==============================================================================================        


# test function        
display_flow(show              = True,
             scen_year         = 0,
             age               = 60,
             s_bal             = 100000,
             bal_pv            = 100000,
             inv_gains         = 1000,
             ann_savings       = 1000,
             ss_payment        = 1000,
             major_inc         = 1000,
             major_exp         = 1000,
             tax_rate          = 0.15,
             tar_ret_spend     = 50000,
             net_ret_spend     = 40000,
             ret_pre_tax_spend = 60000,
             taxes             = 10000,
             end_bal           = 120000
             )
```

The output I receive is exactly what i need. But basically wondering if I need the if show=True. My code is in between the long comment sections of "===".
Everything below it and above it are ways to test my code and parameters I need.

Apologies if made any mistakes on this post, this is my first time posting here asking for help. :(

Answer (score 0):

You do not need show if you always want to print.

If you want to have the option of show then you need an conditional, if else, in your code

```
If show:
  print()
```

I assume you already know using a print will return a string and not the dictionary you have created. If you need it as dict wrap it in {} and use a return instead of print if you need it like a dictionary